# Why java allows private String[][] var[]

Tags: java, arrays, variables

```
private String[][] var[]
```

This code compiles. But shouldn't they make the array on type or variable?

Comment: A strange thing about java, but array brackets on the variable name is allowed. For some reason I've only seen the Oracle tutorial mention that it works at the beginning and never use it beyond that. I'm guessing this split here makes it a 3d array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is the same as this:

```
private String[][][] var;
```

All these forms are equivalent:

```
private String[][][] var;
private String[][] var[];
private String[] var[][];
private String var[][][];
```

And they all mean the same: a three-dimensional array of strings. The `String var[][][]` syntax may seem a bit weird, but it's like that for making C/C++ programmers feel right at home in Java (that's how you normally declare an array type in C/C++).

In Java, the `String[][][] var` syntax is preferred, as it makes clear that the *type* of `var` is `String[][][]`, in the other syntax and its different variations the type information is split before and after the variable - although it's perfectly legal from the compiler's view point, it's harder to read.

Even weirder, all these method declarations are legal and equivalent:

```
String[][][] m()  {return null;}
String[][] m() [] {return null;}
String[] m() [][] {return null;}
String m() [][][] {return null;}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [JLS 10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) in the section about `Array`'s:

> The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, **or both**.
>
> For example:
>
> `byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];`
>   This declaration is equivalent to:
>
> `byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];`

(Emphasis mine)

Note especially the last example where it says `byte[] matrix[]` is equivalent to `byte matrix[][]`.

So no, it is not a bug, simply a design choice.

Comment: Thanks! 

It's rather interesting that in [JLS 10.2 for Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) it is already stated _"We do not recommend "mixed notation" in array variable declarations, where bracket pairs appear on both the type and in declarators; nor in method declarations, where bracket pairs appear both before and after the formal parameter list."_

Answer (score 3):

[The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) says

> "Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C
>   and C++. The general rules for variable declaration, however, permit
>   brackets to appear on both the type and in declarators, so that the
>   local variable declaration"

in [JLS 10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) . In my opinion square brackets (`[]`) in "types" make more sense of an array than that is in declared variables. But in order to confirm to the tradition of C/C++ it was done as the text says in JLS. Another thing is , mixing the square bracket with both types and variables would be confusing to the readers/programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar's answer is pretty good. If one were to read `String[][] var[]` in English, one would say "var is an array of two-dimensional String arrays" thus "var is a three-dimensional String array"

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that shows you when the `[]` position makes a difference.

```
String[] arr, arr2[];
```

The `arr` is an array of `String` whereas the `arr2` is an array of arrays of `String`.

It can as you see be beneficial if you want to declare different arrays on the same line.

And in your example it could have been another `var2` declared on the same line:

```
private String[][] var[], var2;
```